# How to update adapter in onCreate in antoher class?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

So i have an DataAdapter in onCreate method and i want to update it from another class.

```
main_spinList = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.main_spinList);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    main_spinList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    //=========================================Spinner==================
    main_spinList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            filepath = String.valueOf(main_spinList.getSelectedItem());
        }
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            Log.e("klkl", "klkl");
        }
    });
```

**I can update like this from AsyncTask but how can i update the adapter from another class with dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ?**

```
     new FtpGet(){
        public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            list.clear();
             list.addAll(result);
             dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


     }

    }.execute();
```

Another problem is that API 9 devices cant perform AsyncTask like from above in setOnSelectedItem method, it doesnt update the spinner.

Comment: You should only have 1 question per post, post another question for "Another problem …"

Answer (score 1):

I think you better look at ["Getting a Result from an Activity"](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) and ["Retrieving result data from a sub-activity"](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html#usingintents_sub), because you don't need to refresh the adapter until you go back to it's activity.

`onActivityResult()` will allow you to get the status from the sub activity and you can refresh the adapter from the same activity when you are back to it.

In your adapter activity put this code where you start the other activity:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

and add this method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
    if (data.hasExtra("result")) {
      ArrayList<String> result = data.getExtras().getSerializableExtra("result");
      list.addAll(result);
         dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

And when closing the **sub activity** and you want to refresh the adapter use this:

```
  Intent data = new Intent();
  data.putExtra("result", result);
  setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
  finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

use interface in the activity you implement the interface and in the other class you just trigger it. and it it's method you use notify for the adapter.